# how to use filter method in array and print only specific value of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

```
const arr = [
    { value: "Value one",
      label: "Value at one"

    },
    {
      value: "Value 2",
      label: "Value at 2"
    },
    {
      value: "" ,
      label: "Value at 3"
    }
  ]
```

This is my array, which I am passing as a props in different component. But i want to add the filter also, that if the value in array is empty, then do not show its label in child component

```
{arr.filter(val => !val.value).map((data)=>
                  <ChildComponent data ={data}/>
                  )}
```

1. My doubt is how to use **.filter** to hide the empty values. I have written the logic but its not working even when there is a value in an array.
2. when i m doing console.logs to get the value of array:

**console.logs(this.arr)**, output is as follows:

```
1: Object { value: "Value one", label: "Value at one" }
2: Object { value: "Value 2", label: "Value at 2" }
3: Object { value: "", label: "Value at 3" }
```

I want only to get the values of object 1, not sure how to get it. `console.log("sampleData", arr.map(data=>data.label))` gives output as: `[ "Value at one", "Value at 2", "Value at 3" ]` . Though i want the output as only **["Value at one"]**.
Can anyone help me with how to filter the values that exist and print only the 1st value/second value/third value separately from the array.

Comment: Your code is correct. The problem is your `console.log`, which logs the **original** array, not the one you filtered the `value: ""` object out of. `filter` doesn't change the array you call it on, it creates a new array that only contains the items you've chosen to keep. It's fine as it is, good work! :-)

Comment: your filter arr.filter(val => !val.value) perhaps is inverted: you have to use arr.filter(val => !!val.value)

Comment: even after arr.filter(val => !!val.value), I am still getting the label for the value which is null. I want labels to hide, when the value is null in my child component

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how to get the value which is at 1st position

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right the only thing you need to change it `arr.filter(val => !val.value)` tbhat should be `arr.filter(val => val.value != '')` or `arr.filter(val => val.value)` and if you want to valid white spaces you have do a arr.filter(val => val.value.trim() != ''); also the console.log() is showing you the first array, so If you want to get the new value you have to create a new variable assigning that value like `let newarray = arr.filter(val => val.value)` and if you console.log(newarray) it would display the right values.

Comment: i dont want to get the new value, i want to fetch the value at position 1